# Impact on the WVD sessionHosts whose entry is not there in WVDHostRegistrations log analytics table

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, wvd

As per my understanding, session hosts registered with WVD service are logged in WVDHostRegistrations table so can anybody explain the impact if a session host don't have an entry in this table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct impact, as long as you see the session host listed as available in the host pool blade.

The Log Analytics data contains information for the future to keep track of when new session hosts are added to the pool.